# How to use sortby in Java in Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I have two rdd, and would like to merge together, I have the following question,

I tried the following using union, but union does not sort at all, but I don't know how to use sortby here?

```
List<Integer> data1 = Arrays.asList(1, 3, 5);
    List<Integer> data2 = Arrays.asList(2, 4, 6, 8);
    JavaRDD<Integer> rdd1 = sc.parallelize(data1);
    JavaRDD<Integer> rdd2 = sc.parallelize(data2);

    JavaRDD<Integer> rdd = rdd1.union(rdd2);
    rdd.sortBy(w->w._1, false);  //compile error
```

Another question, is there any good way to return the merged the list sorted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below:

```
List<Integer> data1 = Arrays.asList(1, 3, 5);
        List<Integer> data2 = Arrays.asList(2, 4, 6, 8);
        JavaRDD<Integer> rdd1 = sc.parallelize(data1);
        JavaRDD<Integer> rdd2 = sc.parallelize(data2);

        JavaRDD<Integer> rdd = rdd1.union(rdd2);
        int noofpartitions = 1;
        JavaRDD<Integer> rddSorted = rdd.sortBy(f -> f, true, noofpartitions);
        rddSorted.collect().forEach(f -> System.out.println(f));
```

sortBy take three parameters: 1. the function 2. a boolean - true represents ascending order, false-descending order, 3. number of partitions
It will print :

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
8
```

The way you have used is the right one. see this for more details [How to merge two presorted rdds in spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39162275/how-to-merge-two-presorted-rdds-in-spark)

Comment: It worked! Thanks Amit. I am still not sure about the last parameter, do I always use ? in this case. I checked, rdd1, rdd2 are in differernt partition, and after union, rdd consist of 2 partitions.

Comment: Yes, if you are using the Java Api of rdd.sortBy, you have to provide all the three parameters. The third parameter is about the minimum number of partitions required for the resulting RDD.

Comment: If you use the scala api of this rdd.sortBy, then only the first parameter is mandatory, others are initialised by default values. But with Java Api, all three parameters are required